# How to update a <div> on a webserver created by node.js

Tags: node.js, browser, raspberry-pi

I created a webserver with Nodejs and I am writing CPU temperature to console but I would like to update the browser to show the temperature. How is that done ? I cant figure it out....sorry may be a basic question but I do have basic knowledge...

This is my script running in Node.js. Everything works as expected. I get the CPU temperature every 5 seconds but how do I update the  in the html ??

```
var http = require('http');
const { measureCPU } = require('rpi_measure_temp')
var PAGE = "<!DOCTYPE html><body><div id='cpu'>CPU</div></body></html>";
cpu_interval = setInterval(cpu, 5000);

//create a server object:
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.write(PAGE);
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);

//measure CPU temperature
function cpu() {
  measureCPU()
  .then(result => {
    const decimalValue = result.celsius.toFixed(1)
    console.log(decimalValue);
    //how do I write the CPU temperature to the browser ???
    //document.getElementById("cpu").innerHTML = decimalValue;
   })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error) })
}
```